# How can I create a Get request in Node.js to get specific object from json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am optimizing an api, therefore I need to use only data that is relevant for my analysis. I have created a route that pull out of the objects, but I just need 4 of them (account_manager, fronter, closer, management_fee and sales_date)

[image]

I am currently doing this:

[image]

Comment: Please write code here, instead of pasting the screenshot of your code.

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and imgur is blocked in many workplaces and countries. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.find()` with `projection` to retrieve only the relevant field

try this :

```
const model_CancellationKPI = await CancellationKPI.find({},{
    account_manager:1, 
    fronter:1, 
    closer:1, 
    management_fee:1, 
    sales_date:1
}).sort({sales_date:-1})
```

Comment: Hi Ravi. Thank you so much for your support on this. One quick question. Why did you use an object that is not part of  my JSON, which is "date", then you use this object to sort the request? I used sales_date to sort and it worked. BTW, can we use another variable to sort?

Comment: look at your code screenshot, you had written `.sort({date:-1})`, so i thought you have a date field. so i used it.